# .NET Framework licenses

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Can I develop software using the .net Framework, and sell this software to client, other than Windows OS do my client need to purchase the .NET Framework licenses.

Any idea on this.

As I have licenses for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. There is no requirement on any of you to pay money for the .NET framework.
You are even allowed to distribute the correct version of the framework with your software.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to have your client buy anything. Develop your code as you see fit,, and your client can then license your software to run it. .Net framework is a part of windows and is not something extra that you have to buy